# Parallel projection of an angle on a line

Tags: geometry, projection

[image: parallel projection of a corner]

In words: "What is the projection of angle C parallel with the y line?"

Pic related is the visual representation of the question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is the what is the projection of the corner A on the line a, I thought this would have been clear but apparently not. I will specify it under the picture

Comment: show us what have you done so far

Comment: I have looked around on Google quite it bit to try and find a suitable answer, no luck so far. It is part of a series of exercises about Thales theorem. I will post anything relevant I can think of below the question

Comment: What comes to my mind is this http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ObliqueCoordinates.html

Comment: Thank you for your input, while a warped plane coordinate system does seem related (lots of things seem to be related in math) the question is more specifically talking about projecting on the x-axis of the planer system. And I am not quite sure how to project a corner on said axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited my answer to reflect the question in it's current form. The rays of the angle represented by the figure have infinite extent. Although both rays' horizontal extent is only infinite to the left, the angle of the line of projection causes the projected image of the angle to be the entire line onto which the angle is being projected. That is so because the slope of d falls between the slopes of the rays of the angle. If the projection were parallel to a line with slope outside that range, for example f, the image would be a half line with the right endpoint being the image of the apex of the angle.

[image]

Comment: I was talking about the angle, maybe that's why people had troubles understanding the question. My native language is not English, but I think I understand now. Thanks for answering. I will adjust the question to be less ambiguous please do the same to your answer for future reference